# FileUpload event update errors in IE9: XML5632: only one root element is allowed

Tags: jsf, file-upload, internet-explorer-9, primefaces

I am using the `<p:fileUpload>` component of PrimeFaces. After the upload, I have an event "update". With Chrome and Firefox, the update event is fired, but with Internet Explorer (IE9), it isn't. It shows the following error:

> XML5632: only one root element is allowed.

How is this caused and how can I solve it? I am using PF 3.0 Final (downloaded two or three weeks ago), Mojarra 2.1.3, GlassFish 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find a temporary solution.

It's to not use the event `update`, but an `<p:remoteCommand>`.

Like this :

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload auto="true" 
              label="Choisir..." 
              mode="advanced" 
              oncomplete="remoteCommandUpdateDataTable()"
              fileUploadListener="#{uploadBean.handleFileUpload}">
            <f:attribute name="evidence" value="#{evidence}"/>
    </p:fileUpload>
    <p:remoteCommand name="remoteCommandUpdateDataTable" update="myDataTable"/>
</h:form>
```

And it is the same think like `update` but it works with Chrome, Firefox and IE !

Comment: It will be fixed in PrimeFaces 3.1 ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem with IE 9.0.8112.16421 on Win7 X64. I can even reproduce it on PrimeFaces' own showcase page for [single upload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf) and [multiple upload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf), but not on [simple upload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSimple.jsf). I see the following error in the IE console after every upload and the `<p:growl>` does not show up.

```
XML5632: Only one root element is allowed.   
, line 1 character 37
```

This bug was been reported as [issue 3152](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3152), which is been closed as *CantReplicate*.

As of now I'm afraid that there's no other way than to re-report this bug and/or bump the [discussion topic](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17043) on their own forum to get some attention to this issue.

Comment: Ok... I'll try to have a solution on their forum, and if I have one, I post here.

Comment: I don't think there's another solution than to get them to fix their code and provide an updated version of PF 3.0.